# A subset $U$ of a complete metric space such that all continuous functions on $U$ attain a minimum must be closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was working on the following problem:

> Suppose we have a complete metric space $(X,d)$. Show that if every continuous function on a subset $U \subset X$ attains a minimum, then $U$ is closed.

If we suppose that $U$ is not closed, then there is a limit point of $U$, which we call $x$, that is not contained in $U$. Since $x$ is a limit point of $U$, there is a sequence $\langle x_{n} : x_{n} \in U \rangle$ where $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. I am trying to construct a function on $U$ which does not attain a minimum using the above sequence. At this point I consider myself stuck.

Comment: the continuous functions in question have co-domain $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Try $g(x_n)=-n$. Then show that the sequence is closed in $U$. Finally, apply the Tietze Extension Theorem.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? And by "continuous function" is it meant "continuous real-valued function"? (I assume so, but who knows.)

Comment: The problem came from an old qualifying exam. It makes no mention of real-valued function, but for this case, I think it's safe to assume that's what they meant.

Comment: user2566092 already posted what I would have posted if no one had beat me do it.  As an exercise, you might want to prove that the function $f$ defined in that answer is continuous.  You'll need the triangle inequality to do that.  Using _sequences_ in problems like this usually makes things more complicated than they need to be. Using limits of continuous functions on the metric space is usually simpler than using limits of sequences. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Can I ask why we need that $X$ is complete?

Comment: @user5579085 : I'm not sure that that is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your function is real-valued, suppose you have a subset that does not have one of its limit points, say $y$. Then define $f(x) = d(x,y)$. The infimum value is zero but it cannot be obtained within the subset or else the limit point $y$ would be in your subset. So there is no minimum value of $f$ obtained on your subset.

Answer (score 1):

We show that $U^C$ is open. Let $v$ be in $U^C$ and consider the function $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$g(u) = d(u,v).$$ By hypothesis, this function must be obtain its minimum. Its minimum must be positive. If the minimum value of $g$ were $0$, then there must be some $u \in U$ so that $$0=g(u)=d(u,v).$$ Since $d$ is a metric, that would imply that $u=v$, so $v \in U$. But that's not good because $v \in U^C$. So its minimum value must be greater than $0$. Say its minimum is $m$. Then $v \in B_{m}(v) \subseteq U^C$, (since $m$ was the minimum of all distances from $v$ to things in $U$) so $U^C$ must be open, and $U$ must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by contraposition, consider $U:=(0,1)$, and $f(x)=x$. $U$ is not closed, and the continuous function $f$ takes neither a maximum nor a minimum. If you want a min. but not a max., or viceversa, use $V:=[0,1)$ or $W:=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is not closed it has an an accumulation point $a$ outside of $U$, the continuous function $f(x)=d(a,x)$ does not attain a minimum. So $U$ must be closed for all continuous functions to reach a minimum.